# OracleDataAdapter.Fill converting datetime within string

Tags: .net, oracle11g

I have a stored procedure that when executed in sql developer returns a string that contains a field with a string like:

```
'Wow look at this time: 20191113 13:24:44 \r\n now that is one cool datetime'
```

However after the OracleDataAdapter is done with it's Fill operation, the string looks like:

```
'Wow look at this time: 13-NOV-19 \r\n now that is one cool datetime'
```

Is there any way to stop OracleDataAdapter from messing with my strings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a problem of OracleDataAdapter, this is a problem within your stored procedure. Most probably your stored procedure looks like this:

```
create or replace function my_cool_proc
    return varchar2
is
begin
    return 'Wow look at this time: '||sysdate||chr(13)||chr(10)||'now that is one cool datetime';
end;
```

In this case the `sysdate` (data type `date`) gets converted to `varchar2` thanks to Oracle's implicit conversion rules when concatenating (`||` operator) strings. When you run the stored procedure from SQL Developer, your SQL Developer's session NLS settings are applied for conversion of `date` values to `varchar2` values. When you run the stored procedure from .NET code, your .NET database driver's NLS settings are applied for the said conversion.

To make the returned value stable you have to convert (= format) the `sysdate` to a string prior to the string concatenation within your stored procedure, i.e.,

```
create or replace function my_cool_proc
    return varchar2
is
begin
    return 'Wow look at this time: '||to_char(sysdate, 'yyyymmdd hh24:mi:ss')||chr(13)||chr(10)||'now that is one cool datetime';
end;
```

Comment: Your guess as to how my stored procedure looks is exactly correct.  I am not very familiar with Oracle so I just did what 'made sense'.  To me if I am telling a system that I want a 'string' as my return type then I expect it to do just that.  I don't expect it to change the output depending on the environment which is running the query.  But hey, that's why me and Oracle don't get along ;-)  Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: @Bitfiddler, many languages allow for concatenating, e.g., a number to a string. That's where an implicit data type conversion kicks in. And how do you say in these cases how should that concatenated number look like? A "minus/plus" sign prepended or appended? Grouping symbol a space, a comma, a period, or simply nothing? A decimals separator a comma, or a period? Unless you provide an explicit conversion format, the language *must* use *something*. And Oracle uses DB session's national settings... as do other languages by using, e.g., the OS national settings. A feature, not a bug. :-)

Comment: Anyway, glad to have been of help.

Comment: I would expect the statement to use the database servers regional settings to convert to string unless otherwise instructed.  That way the string is always generated consistently no matter who ran the query.  If the writer of the sql is unhappy with the default format, they can then specify the desired to-string conversion.  If the writer wants to support changing the format depending on a client, I would expect that to come in as a parameter so that the consumer can specify/predict the output consistently.

Comment: Frequently the system running the query is not the final consumer of the output, so for Oracle to assume the date format of the client connecting to the database is, in my opinion, most certainly not a feature.  But I understand where this comes from now so thankfully I can get the behavior I expect without any hacks and in the end that is most important!

Comment: A second argument for why this is not a 'good' feature, is that 3 other devs that I talked to who use Oracle all the time (but in Java and not .NET) did not know this behavior and simply blamed it on the .NET adapter (which is where I got that idea).  So if I was the only noob who was confused by this, then sure call it a feature.  But if 3 other devs, plus the 12 other people who viewed this question, didn't know the answer... I put this in the 'poorly considered feature' bucket ;-)

Comment: @Bitfiddler, I can see where you're heading. It's an unfortunate feature, yes. A feature that many people I met so far had troubles comprehending. It's in the same set of "misfeatures" as, e.g., MS Excel's or OOo Calc's national character semantics when dealing with, let's say, export/import of CSVs. What I'm trying to say that this "misfeature" is more common than you may want to see.

Comment: Indeed, there is no shortage of misfeatures out in the world.  Thanks again for clarifying this one for me.  I will spread the good word in my neck of the woods if I see my fellow devs struggling with it.